# Visual Studio Code shortcut for terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

I simply cannot find an answer by googling, for, what is the **command line shortcut** that stands for **Visual Studio Code**. For example to check the version, and I know I can just use its built-in terminal and type --version but what if I want to check that from outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply code.

```
code --version // to check version
code // opens visual studio code
```